# Is there any way to parse and display data from Text/csv/xml file without a webserver

Tags: jquery, html

Is there any way to parse and display data from Text/csv/xml file through html script without a webserver. i need to run it by double clicking without opening it from webserver.

(i have some data which can be saved in any of these formats (Text or Csv or XMl - its a details of our parish members) i need to display it using the html file. need to run standalone pcs without webserver.

is there any way.. please help me out.

thanks & regards
Sibi Mathew

Comment: `Text/csv/xml file` covers an insanely wide range of input types, so you may want to narrow that down a bit.  And it's not clear where that file resides - is it on your local computer, as might be derived from the fact that you double click it?

Comment: They double-click the file and it opens your html "script?"

Comment: Much more info please.

Comment: (i have some data which can be saved in any of these formats (Text or Csv or XMl - its a details of our parish members) i need to display it using the html file. need to run standalone pcs without webserver. sorry for being not descriptive..

Comment: @SibiMathew your comment it still not descriptive enough, you are just repeating what you put in your question initially.

Comment: @ SOfanatic i editted my question also with the details...

Answer (score 0):

HTML – is not programming language, but markup language. That means you can't use it to parse any kind of data.
Since you need to work with uploaded files (handle uploads) resume short answer to your question is no. You can't do what you need without of any serverside code.